# Exception when calling wait()

Tags: android

I am implementing an application in which I play two sounds ("**touchandshow**" followed by "**tiger**"). This is done in my `looper` method. I call it a first time, then call `wait()`, then call `looper` again.

The problem is that I get an exception in the LogCat from the `wait()` call.

Here is my code:

```
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.touchandshow);
    mPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tiger);

    try {

        looper();
        wait(2000);

        looper();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void looper() {
    CountDownTimer aCounter;
    aCounter = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mPlayer.start();
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            mPlayer2.start();
        }
    };
    aCounter.start();

}
```

And the LogCat:

```
    07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.AudioTesting/com.AudioTesting.AudioTesting}: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:326)
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.AudioTesting.AudioTesting.onCreate(AudioTesting.java:25)
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-29 10:20:09.412: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1188):     ... 11 more
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the error you got.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
```

Your problem is this message. You can't call `wait` on an object you haven't locked first. `wait` is meant for synchronization, not as a generic "sleep" facility.

If you just want to pause your thread, use:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

inside your try block instead.

Comment: Well then how do I lock my object?

Comment: @Nobleleader13245: that often involves `synchronized` blocks.

Comment: And if you need to be able to interrupt this sleep before it expires?

Comment: Then you need to `interrupt` it (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()), @A.Grandt

Comment: But note that it's generally a bad idea. Without some other properly synchronized indicator, you have no way of knowing if that thread is indeed inside that specific sleep. So you have no way of knowing if it's safe to interrupt it. Using a proper lock with a wait/notify is a better idea, @A.Grandt.

Comment: I ended up using wait, and surrounded it with a synchronized block, using an object for that thread alone. And another synchronized were required around the interrupt call as well, using the same lock object. (in an Android ASyncTask)