# Android: switching screen on and off programmatically at specific time intervals

Tags: android, screen-brightness

I need to create an app in which the screen goes off for some time (say 10 seconds) and then goes on, displays a message for 2 seconds and is turned again off. And this keeps on repeating until a button is clicked. (ie. I want to stop this activity when the button is clicked). I have tried implementing this by changing the screen brightness.

My code is somewhat like this:

```
float dim = 0;
float bright = 1.0f;
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp=getWindow().getAttributes();
bright = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
wait(2000);
lp.screenBrightness = dim;
wait(10000);
lp.screenBrightness = bright;
```

If I'm not wrong, this should work fine. But when I run it, it goes dim and then shows an error occurred, force-close message.

Any help will be appreciated.

here is the logcat error:

```
02-22 11:12:50.804: D/AndroidRuntime(10871): Shutting down VM
02-22 11:12:50.804: W/dalvikvm(10871): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wakelock/com.example.wakelock.WakeLock}:java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871):    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871):    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:395)
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871):    at com.example.wakelock.WakeLock.onCreate(WakeLock.java:42)
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
02-22 11:12:50.859: E/AndroidRuntime(10871):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post your LogcatError...!!!!

Comment: here's the problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/6869014/605027

Comment: i tried using Thread.sleep(2000) instead of wait(2000) inside the try catch block. but now the screen does not show any changes at all. it is just idle, nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem using handler.  for any future references, here is the code.

```
 float dim = 0.004f; // if you set this 0, it wont work. 0.004 is the least value
 float bright = 1.0f;
 Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            lp.screenBrightness= bright;
                            getWindow().setAttributes(lp);                              
                            final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
                            Timer t = new Timer();                              
                            t.schedule(new TimerTask() { 
                                    public void run() { 
                                            handler.post(new Runnable() { 
                                                    public void run() { 
                                                    lp.screenBrightness=dim;
                                                    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
                                                    } 
                                            }); 
                                    } 
                            }, 2000);   //  flashing of screen
                        }
                    });
```